# Running content script on "chrome-extension://" url?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, privileges

Is it possible to have a chrome extension be active on another extension's `chrome-extension://` page? (In particular, the ability to run a content script would be especially handy.) I have an ebook reader extension and a speed reading extension (my own), and I'd like to use the two simultaneously. Thank you!

Comment: There should be an existing answer for that but in short you can write a devtools panel extension (example: Storage Area Explorer) that can access the currently open page of another extension, or use chrome.debugger API.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm! It's possible one of those would do the trick, still looking into it, but if possible a much more streamlined solution would be to run a content script; is this possible? (edited question to reflect this)

Comment: Content scripts are for web pages.